# how to get around ga4 incompatible combination of dimensions and metrics

Tags: google-analytics-4

I’m trying to use the reporting API but I am getting a "[GA4] Data compatibility" error and can’t get the data that I want.

I want to get newUsers counts by minute but minute dimension and newUsers metrics are incompatible. Is there a way to get around this?

(We are transitioning from Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4 and this has not been a problem with Universal Analytics)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In this link [GA4 Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/), you can check if the metrics and dimensions you want are compatible or not. Remember that you need to enter your account and property ID as requested in  [image: requested info] this photo.
As you choose dimensions & metrics (by clicking the checkbox next to their name), they will be added here. Incompatible dimensions & metrics will be grayed out.